# HTTP to HTTPS redirect does't work in IIS

Tags: php, redirect, iis, server

I am trying to redirect all the links with HTTP to HTTPS in my PHP website.
I am using IIS server and having a web.config file to write the redirect rule. After trying a different set of server rules from multiple blogs, when I did not find the solution I am writing a question on Stack Overflow.

When I implement the below rule, My website goes on a redirect loop. I am suspecting that HTTP to HTTPS redirect is working but it is not able to add HTTPS condition. Which means, even if I request HTTPS URL it is getting redirected and going on a redirect loop.

```
<rule name="Redirect to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Is this anything to this the server settings as well?
In my server variable, I can see that it says HTTPS is off.

```
[HTTPS] => off
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Microsoft-IIS/8.5
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: According to your rule, I have created a test demo on my side, it works well, It doesn't go to redirect loop. I guess you may have other rule which cause the redirect loop. I suggest you could try to follow the lex provided article to enable FRT to troubleshoot. Besides, if you have other url rewrite rule, you could post them for to us to test.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have only one redirect rule. Even I am thinking why exactly it goes in a loop.

Comment: It can be a server settings related issue. As I mentioned above, the Server variable shows me [HTTPS] => off